# Python3.5 merging dictionaries without replacing values and grouping them

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, python-3.5

I am trying to merge two different dictionaries and i have spend alot of time on this but all in vain. For example i have following input:

```
a = {}
a['name'] = 'john'
a['gender'] = 'male'
a['age'] = 20
a = {'name':'john', 'gender':'male', 'age': 20}

b = {}
b['name'] = 'Ana'
b['gender'] = 'female'
b['age'] = 15
b = {'name':'Ana', 'gender':'female', 'age': 15}
```

I need to append dict again and again for different users. I am using Python3.5. Now i want something that gives me output as following:

```
Final = { {'name':'john', 'gender':'male', 'age': 20}, {'name':'Ana', 'gender':'female', 'age': 15} }
```

Please let me know how can i do this. I would be grateful

Regards,
Hassaan

Comment: That latter thing isn't a dictionary, because it doesn't have keys. It looks like it's a set, but its elements are dictionaries, and that isn't allowed (you can't have mutable things in a set). You have to rethink what you want exactly.

Comment: If you just want a list, then `Final = [a, b]` would work...

Comment: Thankyou for kind response. Now i get to know that i have to put dicts in lists to join them together :)